# VBA - Search value in a column and reorder them in a new column

Tags: vba, excel

in a column I have multiple values (Vat numbers) but not in consecutive rows, for example in A1, A5, A8,...
I need to copy each value from column A and paste them in a new column but reordered in consecutive rows, for example B1,B2,B3,...

The following macro does this job but only if in the value it is included the symbol "@" because it uses the function "Array" (if I replace @ with numbers as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, I get the same VAT number multiple times and I do not require it).

```
Sub Copy_To_Another_Sheet_1()
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim MyArr As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rcount As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim NewSh As Worksheet

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

     MyArr = Array("@")

    Set NewSh = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A100")

        Rcount = 0

        For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)

            'If you use LookIn:=xlValues it will also work with a
            'formula cell that evaluates to "@"
            'Note : I use xlPart in this example and not xlWhole 'MyArr(I)
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I), _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = Rng.Address
                Do
                    Rcount = Rcount + 1

                    NewSh.Range("A" & Rcount).Value = Rng.Value

                    ' Use this if you only want to copy the value
                    ' NewSh.Range("A" & Rcount).Value = Rng.Value

                    Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
            End If
        Next I
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks
Marco

Comment: Hint: You can check the VAT number before adding to destination sheet using the same functionality you are using.

Comment: What about copying the range, remove duplicates and then sort?